# CoordinatorLayout rendering issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-coordinatorlayout, coordinator-layout

I was trying out **Android Studio**. Upon creating a new project, The auto generated *xml* has a *CoordinatorLayout* as root. But my *xml* preview just does not render. It builds OK and also renders if I comment out the *CoordinatorLayout*.

[image]

And this is when I turn on "*preview android versions*" :

[image]

There are no error messages shown too. So I have absolutely no idea what's going on. What do ya think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem and there are two or three methods to fix that.

**First:** Update the Sdk platform to the latest version, your currently version was 21, so update it to the latest one.

**Second:** you can try to cache/restart in the menu.

**Or perhaps,** inatalling the latest version of android studio (even on canary) can fix that.

Most of the time it can be fixed with latest `SDK platform`, just choose it from the preview's above to `23` or latest version.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try.

Comment: Yw, remember, updating the api is the best choice :)